# How to pass parameter with baseurl

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, base-url

In that case user going to update his details. But form submission is failed i want to redirect users to his form again.

I know this method is working.

```
redirect(base_url('Time_Mgt_Con/time_employee'));
```

But  tried to do like this.But it's not working

```
$eid = $this->input->post("eid");
redirect(base_url('Time_Mgt_Con/time_employee/'$eid''));
```

Comment: Try this, redirect(base_url('Time_Mgt_Con/time_employee/').$eid);

Comment: @BukhariBaBa Yes.It's working

Answer (score 0):

```
// append the variable to the base url

$eid = $this->input->post("eid");
redirect(base_url("Time_Mgt_Con/time_employee/" . $eid));
```

Answer (score 0):

just use $this->load->library('user_agent').
Note: if you use redirect you dont need to write base_url.

use an if condition like this:

```
if($formsubmit){
redirect('Time_Mgt_Con/time_employee');
}else{
redirect( $this->agent->referrer() );
}
```